# Reading Regular Expressions from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to write a function that takes two inputs:

**1 - The URL for a web page
2 - The name of a text file containing some regular expressions**

My function should read the text file line by line (each line being a different regex) and then it should execute the given regex on the web page source code. However, I've ran in to trouble doing this:

*example*
Suppose I want the address contained on a Yelp with URL = http://www.yelp.com/biz/liberty-grill-cork
where the regex is `\<address\>\s*([^<]*)\\b\s*<`. In Python, I then run:

```
address = re.search('\<address\>\s*([^<]*)\\b\s*<', web_page_source_code)
```

The above **will work**, however, if I just write the regex in a text file as is, and then read the regex from the text file, then it won't work. So reading the regex from a text file is what is causing the problem, how can I rectify this?

**EDIT:** This is how I'm reading the regexes from the text file:

```
with open("test_file.txt","r") as file:
    for regex in file:
        address = re.search(regex, web_page_source_code)
```

Just to add, the reason I want to read regexes from a text file is so that my function code can stay the same and I can alter my list of regexes easily. If anyone can suggest any other alternatives that would be great.

Comment: I believe the `\\b` should be just `\b` in the text file.

Comment: To parse HTML, consider using an HTML parsing library like BeautifulSoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @MightyPork is correct. The extra backslashes are needed in Pythong source code to escape the backslash in its string literals (although the usual preference is to use raw strings with `r'...'`). They're not needed in files, since it's not parsed like program code.

Comment: @MightyPork I changed the \\b to a \b and it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string has some backlashes and other things escaped to avoid special meaning in Python string, not only the regex itself.

You can easily verify what happens when you print the string you load from the file. If your backslashes doubled, you did it wrong.

The text you want in the file is:

*File*

```
\<address\>\s*([^<]*)\b\s*<
```

Here's how you can check it

```
In [1]: a = open('testfile.txt')

In [2]: line = a.readline()

-- this is the line as you'd see it in python code when properly escaped

In [3]: line
Out[3]: '\\<address\\>\\s*([^<]*)\\b\\s*<\n'

-- this is what it actually means (what re will use)

In [4]: print(line)
\<address\>\s*([^<]*)\b\s*<
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the regex in my text file to what you suggested but it still doesn't seem to work. Would you mind checking my above code (see the edit I made) which explains how I'm reading the regexes from my text file? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong there?

Comment: I'd suggest you check if your regex is in fact correct using  https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to get it working. For anyone who wants to read regular expressions from text files, you need to do the following:

1. Ensure that regex in the text file is entered in the right format (thanks to MightyPork for pointing that out)
2. You also need to remove the newline '\n' character at the end

So overall, your code should look something like:

```
a = open("test_file.txt","r")
line = a.readline()
line = line.strip('\n')
result = re.search(line,page_source_code)
```

Comment: ah that was the culprit. Glad you sorted that out. (In my test file there was no newline, so I didn't think of that..)